# Adding a DC Power Adapter Socket to Sony AM/FM Radio

Tags: dc, radio, battery-operated

A friend has asked me to do a mod on their basic Sony AM/FM Radio (Model ICF306).  It's 3V based but only accepts batteries.  I thought about opening it up and soldering a 5.5mm Socket across the +/- battery terminals, but then figured this was probably not a good idea.  If the batteries were present then you'd have the battery and the DC adapter in parallel.  What's the best way to workaround this.  Perhaps a Single Throw Double Pole switch (so you can either manually select battery or DC adapter pack sources) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most barrel jacks have a switch for just this purpose.

Typically you will put the switch in the negative side if the adapter is center-positive. You only need to disconnect the battery on one side when the adapter is plugged in.

See also [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10731/wiring-a-dc-socket-why-three-pins) answer- image from there-
[image]

Pin 3 will go to the battery (-) and will be disconnected when the plug is inserted (assuming center positive).